# Start Gradle from Java and run it in same JVM as main program

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle

I have an Eclipse plug-in which has to start a Gradle build script. I currently use the SpringSource Eclipse plug-in for that. Here is my code:

```
public void run(String project, String task) throws FastOperationFailedException, CoreException {  
    File projectLocation = new File(project).getAbsoluteFile();
    GradleProject gradleProject = GradleCore.create(projectLocation);

    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    System.out.println("MyWorkspace1: " + workspace.toString());
    TaskUtil.execute(gradleProject, null,  Arrays.asList("mytask"), new NullProgressMonitor());
 }
```

This code works fine. The Gradle process is started and does its duties. However, Gradle is started in a new JVM. I would need to pass objects between my plug-in and the Gradle process, so I would need to have them run on the same JVM. Does anyone know if this is possible or if I could pass objects to Gradle without serializing them?

## Update

The overall idea is to create a way to pass the IJavaProjet to Gradle. MoDisco is a tool for model-driven reverse engineering and I need to call it as part of my builtd script. It only oprrates on IJavaProject instances, which can be easily retrieved inside the Eclipse JVM but are hard to get otherwise. So to sum it up, I would need to:

1. create a IJavaProject inside the Eclise plug-in
2. pass it to gradle, which woud start MoDisco as a task
3. perform some other EMF operations on the result of the above task
4. (optionally) return the object back to my Eclipse plug-in

Comment: There is no supported way to run Gradle in the same process (and you wouldn't want to anyway). What objects do you need to pass? Have you checked out the Gradle tooling API?

Comment: My scenario is to "misuse" Gradle for orchestrating EMF transformations (Eclipse Modeling Framework). For this, I would need to pass objects to and from Gradle without them getting serialized (since they are huge, serializing takes several hours per object).

Comment: There isn't any supported way to run Gradle in the same process. (There is an internal property to run the tooling API in embedded mode, but this may go away at any time.) I'm not sure why/if running Gradle in the same process would be necessary/useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I would like to run it in the same process to share objects. If you can think of any other idea how to pass objects to gradle, I'm happy to try it. Thanks again!

Comment: Still not sure why you need to pass objects to Gradle, as none of this is explained in your question.

Comment: I added a bit on that part as edit to my original post. Just a few words: I want to use Gradle`s dependecy graph to orchestrate the Execution of EMF plug-ins. For that, I would need to pass Eclipse objects to Gradle.

Comment: Why would you want to use Gradle here? Why not use MoDisco (more) directly from your Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Because I need to create a flexible way to orchestrate several EMF tools (ATL, ATL/EMTF, Acceleo, XText). I planed to create a task type for each so I could just orchestrate them by using Gradle`s build-in depenendcy graph (i.e. Task.dependsOn). This works for most,but MoDisco needs a IJavaProject, which I only get inside Eclipse. Again, my task is to create a EMF orchestration language and I hoped to (mis-)use Gradle for that.

Comment: If serialization is not an option, Gradle is probably not the right tool for this.

Comment: Ok. If you add an answer,I`ll mark it as correct. Thanks for your help!